# Tagging a SVN Trunk/Branch code using XCode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, svn

I am using XCode 4.3 and have integrated it with SVN. How do we tag a particular code from the XCode.

I want to copy and tag the entire trunk code to Tags folder. I used to do this with XCode 3.2.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this same problem, and I just ended up using the command line, easy enough:

```
svn copy <svn root path>/trunk <svn root path>/tags/<new tag>
```

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the ultimate solution. But I really miss that feature in XCode :-(.